# servicestack: what is the limit on the "limited use"?

Tags: servicestack

https://servicestack.net/pricing

We need a thin slice of servicestack, and are looking for options to reduce the cost.

What is included in the Starter version?

Answer (score 0):

The **Limited Usage** link on the [pricing page](https://servicestack.net/pricing) links to ServiceStack's [Free Quotas on the download page](https://servicestack.net/download#free-quotas).

Comment: Heck, I was on that page and didn't understand what was being said until now. It is not clear from that list what the limit is if we use service stack to create a server side REST or SOAP endpoint what the limit is?

Comment: @Jonesome They are the only technical restrictions applicable to unlicensed projects. The limit for any REST/SOAP Services is 10 operations.

Comment: Thanks! I think servicestack pricing is a blocker. We will find another solve. (Bummer, as I really like it)